# Truncate an AnsiString

Tags: c++, c++builder, ansistring

I'm working with Rad Studio, c++ builder.  The size of the AnsiString size is ~2^31 characters. How should I check the length?

```
if(ExportFileName.Length() > ??? )
  {
    ExportFileName. ???
  }
  m_ActionsHelper.LastPdfFile = ExportFileName;
```

Comment: For data that large, I'd say that `AnsiString` is not the correct container. If it's data from a file consider using memory-mapping instead.

Comment: As for your problem, the value you're looking for is `0x7ffffffful`. However, if you get a length over that value it's already to late.

Comment: and how i should truncate it? using Delete?

Comment: As I stated in my comment, by then it's already to late and you have already gone over the limit. If `AnsiString` allows you to even go over such a limit. I still strongly suggest you consider other options before storing such large amounts in an `AnsiString`, but if you insist I then recommend you change your code to check the length before appending to the string. If the current length plus the length of the string you want to append is to long, then don't append. So no need to truncate.

Comment: How are you storing more than `MaxInt` (0x7FFFFFFF) chars in an `AnsiString` to begin with? You should have gotten memory errors from the RTL long before the `AnsiString` reached that size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I see it in the [reference](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__AnsiString__Delete.html), both parameters of `Delete` are `int`, which maximum value way lower than `2^31`. It seems you don't need such a check.

Anyway, if you'd like to get integer power of `2`, you can use binary shift operator:

```
1ull << 31
```

Binary shift operator manipulates bits of integer in such a way that all bits are shifted in the required direction. For example,

```
Operation   Bits   Shifted bits 10-based
1 << 1    00000001   00000010      2
1 << 2    00000001   00000100      4
4 << 2    00000100   00010000      16
```

And so on. So `1ull << 31` is `2^31`. `ull` means we use 64-bits number, because `int` is to small for it.

To delete the surplus tail using Delete it should be like

```
ExportFileName.Delete(1 << 10, ExportFileName.Length());
```

or

```
ExportFileName.SetLength(1 << 10);
```

And probably you don't need to check the length beforehand. Just `Delete` or `SetLength`. If it already satisfies, no action will be performed.

Comment: and to truncate the string i should use Delete?

Comment: I don't know this framework, but as I see it in the reference, it should be like `ExportFileName.Delete(1 << 31, ExportFileName.Length());`.

Comment: But length returns int, an 1<<31 is not hexa?

Comment: @AlexandraTupu No. In C++ only literals can be represented in hex.

Comment: the string is the same, is not modified

Comment: @AlexandraTupu Are you sure it was longer than 2^31 before the check? If not, it shouldn't be modified.

Comment: Cool! At stackoverflow.com we upvote or accept answers if we think they were helpful.

Comment: `1 << 31` is 0x80000000, which is greater than `MaxInt` (0x7FFFFFFF). `Delete()` takes `int` as input, `1 << 31` is simply too large a value for it to handle, and will wrap to negative when passed as an `int`. `1 << 30` is 0x40000000, which is less than `MaxInt`. Also note the 1st parameter of `Delete()` is a 1-based index, and the 2nd parameter is the number of chars to delete.  When removing chars off the end of the string, you can alternatively use `SetLength()` instead of `Delete()`.

Comment: The return type of `AnsiString::Length` is `int`, which is 32-bit signed. So this test can never succeed properly. Also, the `SetLength` function takes `int` as parameter; passing `1ull << 31` to it invokes implementation-defined behaviour (probably passing a negative value)

Comment: @M.M I think I noted it at the post. Could you please read it?

Comment: I moved the warning of integer overflow to top of the post and fixed parameters of `Delete` and `SetLength`, so nobody could be confused.